# Exception error when getting master page in powershell

Tags: powershell, custom-masterpage, exception-handling

I wanted to see which site collections in our 2010 environment are not following the rules and are deactivating the Master Page in the settings.

I have some powershell code that works just fine, and it returns back the correct information but I get a bunch of exception errors.  Anybody have any suggestions on how what I might be doing wrong?

Error message:

> Exception calling "GetFile" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall
>   within the expected range." At line:13 char:35
>   +         $MasterPage = $Web.GetFile <<<< ($Web.MasterUrl)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Here is my powershell script that I am using:

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


    #Get all site collections of provided web app

$SiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All

   #Loop through all site collections
   foreach($Site in $SiteCollections)
    {
       #Loop through all Sub Sites
       foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
       {   
        #Get the Master Page
        $MasterPage = $Web.GetFile($Web.MasterUrl)
        if ($MasterPage.name -ne "corp.master")
             {
                     $MasterPage.Name  + " : " + $Web.Url 
             }
       }

    }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just check the [CustomMasterUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.custommasterurl.aspx) and [MasterUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.masterurl.aspx) properties that are on the SPWeb object itself and bypass the slow and expensive `GetFile()` altogether?

```
        if ($Web.MasterUrl.EndsWith("corp.master") -eq $false)
           $Web.MasterUrl + " : " + $Web.Url     
        }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a little?  I originally had used Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select URL, MasterUrl.  But I wasnt sure how to filter out what I needed.  I wanted it to return only the site collections that were using something other than "corp.master".

Comment: updated answer to include an example

Comment: Thanks, Dave! I ended up using that bit of code and modifying it a little to output to a text file.